# Please help me understand primecoin mining performance

Tags: primecoin

I've just started mining primecoin over my hp proliant dl380 g5 server with e5420.

So I'm using ypool.net as the pool and using their latest software: jhPrimeminer_RdBBeta4.0F2_x64.zip

When I check the site stats I see i get a value of 0.0514 share/h. Is this all good or am I having poor performance?

As I'm new to primecoin, having difficulties to understand it.